# Not able to call Salesforce REST web service from Java web application as Salesforce has disabled SSL 3.0 encryption

Tags: java, rest, ssl

What needs to be done/changed from the java application side to access Salesforce orgs?

Comment: This post [Impact on Java clients due to disabling SSL 3.0 encryption in Salesforce](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26943753/impact-on-java-clients-due-to-disabling-ssl-3-0-encryption-in-salesforce) suggests you may have to move to at least Java 1.6.

Comment: I don't see any issue on Java version "1.7.0_45". So like Keith suggested you could try updating Java.

Answer (score -1):

Hi you should change it with ssl2.5 by selecting from dropdownlist